# How to make ASP.NET button call client side javascript and not do postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a web app in ASP.NET with a C# code behind.  The main login page is going to have a sort of touchpad type UI where there are buttons for 0-9 to enter a pin #.

So, I'm new to ASP.NET and to JavaScript both.  When these numeric buttons are clicked on the UI, nothing needs to be done on the server side - there shouldn't be any postback at all.  All that needs be done is append a number to a label's text.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that in JavaScript, without the button causing any kind of postback.

To make the example much simpler, let's just say I have a UI with a single label and single button on the screen, and everytime you click this single button, it should append a 1 to the label's text.  Here's my .aspx, but when I try to run this, I get a "Object Expected" exception at runtime...

EDIT: I've modified my example to include the suggestions made in answers below, and still am having issues.  To reproduce, this .aspx code can be copied into the default.aspx of a new VS Web Application project, and run it and click the 1 button; it should append a 1 to the label's value, but it throws an "Object Expected" exception.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestJavascript._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Table ID="baseTable" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <asp:TableRow ID="labelRow" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100" Height="30">
          <asp:TableCell ID="labelCell" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%" Height="100%" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
            <asp:Label ID="inputLbl" runat="server"/>
          </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow ID="buttonRow" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
          <asp:TableCell ID="buttonCell" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="1" Height="70px" Width="70px" OnClientClick="btn1Click()"/>
          </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
      </asp:Table>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script type="txt/javascript">
    void btn1Click()
    {
        document.getElementById('<%= inputLbl.ClientID %>').value += "1";
        return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if the button is never meant to postback, it should be a regular `input type="button"` not an `asp:Button`.

Comment: The button may never need to PostBack, but its properties might be modified from server code (`Visible`, `Enabled`, `Text`, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a variable name should not start with a number, so replace `1Btn` with a significative name (`btnAppendOne`).

1. Bind the `onclick` client event to your `Button`, in your `PageLoad` method:

   ```
   btnAppendOne.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return btnAppendOneClick();");
   ```
2. Use the correct javascript (`return false` should cancel the postback):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnAppendOneClick()
        {
            var updatedLabel = document.getElementById('<%=inputLbl.ClientID %>');
            updatedLabel.innerHTML = updatedLabel.innerHTML + "1";
            return false;
        }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: I just edited my answer, I had first read you wanted to increase the label's value, but you want to append a "1" to it.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm still getting an "Object expected" exception at runtime because its not finding the inputLbl.  Also, it says the AutoPostBack attribute is not valid for an asp Button.  I'm using VS 2008 targeted at .NET 3.5.

Comment: Ok you had set `void` instead of `function` before your function's name. AutoPostBack is not applicable for ASP Buttons, so I guess simply returning false should prevent the post back.

Comment: Tried changing it from void to function, the way you showed, but with that one change made to the example code in my edited question, I am still getting an "Object Expected" exception at runtime.  Not sure why; and I'm not really sure how to go about even debugging javascript - it's kind aggravating when I can't pinpoint why the exception is happening, and I get not details other than "Object Expected".

Comment: A simple way to debug your javascript would be to `alert` your values....so try adding `alert(updatedLabel);` after the `document.getElementById` and tell us what's displayed in the prompt box.

Comment: It throws an exception before it gets to the alert.  In fact, if I take everything out of the btn1Click() function and replace it with just a simple alert, it still gives me an "Object Expected" exception.

Comment: Obviously, you must have a syntax error in your page. Check carefully if all your tags are correctly closed... Btw, do you still have the `OnClientClick` property set to your button? if so, delete that.

Comment: Right now, I have exactly the code that's listed in the original question, except I changed the function declaration so it uses "function" instead of "void", and I've removed the OnClientClick="btn1Click()" piece, and put that in the page_load on the code behind with a btn1.Attributes.Add(...) like you showed.  Still the same problem, and I don't see any issues with syntax.  If I explicitly add an alert like btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('someAlert')"); in the code behind, it works, but if I replace that with a call to "btn1Click()" it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes...that must be because the function is `btnAppendOneClick()`.

Comment: No, in my example its btn1Click().   I've made this work now by doing this in the code behind....     this.btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "inputLbl.innerHTML +='1'; return false;");     But if I do the same thing and try to use the function like this....    this.btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "btn1Click()");    ...it doesn't work

Comment: Nope, I've got a semi colon.  It's pretty weird, I'm not sure what's going on, but for now I've made it work with inline javascript so I'll leave it at that and try to figure it out more later maybe.  I really appreciate all your help!  Already gave a +1.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `OnClientClick` attribute for the asp button and add `return false;` which prevents the postback:

```
<asp:Button ID="1Btn" runat="server" Text="1" Height="70px" Width="70px" 
    OnClientClick="btn1Click(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `return false;` statement, it will stop from postback; If you need postback then `return true;` from function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
void btn1Click()
{
    this.inputLbl.Text += "1";
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just as a note, his button is not linked to call his function yet. ;)

Comment: I tried this too, but even after I link up my function to the button's OnClientClick event, it fails here with an "Object Expected" error, like it's not finding the inputLbl object, or that object is null or something.  The label doesn't have any text in it at first; do I need to initialize it to an empty string or something at page load?

Comment: You need document.getElementById('<%= inputLbl.ClientID' %>).value += "1"; instead of this.inputLbl.Text += "1"; I have updated my answer. Tell me if you have any problems

Comment: I've tried this.  See my edited example code above; I get an "Object Expected" exception when clicking btn1.  I've implemented it exactly how suggested as far as I can tell; do you see anything wrong that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo in your Script tag.. First Line (1)

```
 <script type="**text**/javascript">
void btn1Click()
{
    document.getElementById('<%= inputLbl.ClientID %>').value += "1";
    return false;
}
```